# Is there a way to color the command you type into the prompt in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, colors, highlight, prompt

I use quick navigation shortcuts a lot in bash to jump a word back or forward or delete a word. The problem is, I never know where exactly the cursor ends up after the jump, especially when punctuation is involved.

I thought it would be a nice productivity addition if I could color the word before/after the cursor in a way that I could tell from that where the cursor will jump or what would be deleted.

Examples:

```
$ grep '^[0-9]+$' /var/tmp/foo-bar/whatever
```

```
$ grep '^[0-9]+$' /var/tmp/foo-bar/whatever
```

```
$ grep '^[0-9]+$' /var/tmp/foo-bar/whatever
```

[image: examples]

Comment: You'd have to modify the `bash` program to accomplish this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: zsh has syntax highlighting for the current line, I believe.